# Add KeyValuePair to new Dictionary in nested select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a large nested that selects new classes, which works good, but I would like to Add a new KeyValuePair to the "TestDictionary" on the fly, that has value from "B".

```
from a ... from b ...
select new c
{
    TestC = b.Foo,
    TestDictionary = new Dictionary(b.Parameters.ToDictionary(
                  x => x.ParameterKey, x => (object)x.ParameterValue)) 
// .Add(new.. "SomeKey", b.SomeValue) ?
    }).ToList()
```

Tried to use the Add method, but cant get it to work. Is it possible to Add one keyvaluepair to the newly created dictionary on the fly?

Thanks in advance

/Lasse

Comment: I'm guessing this is because the `Add(...)` method of the `Dictionary` class does not return a value that you can use inside a dynamic statement like this. My advice would be to refactor this into something more readable as heavily embedded Linq statements can be very messy.

Comment: Enumerbale.Concat will concatenate two IEnumerables. This should probably help if you append something to b.Parameters before converting to a dictionary (depending on the complexity of b.Parameters).

Comment: Yep, but for now I need some sort of quick'n'dirty fix before xmas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the collection initializer syntax. When the `Add()` method takes more than one parameter, as with a `Dictionary`, you wrap each in curly braces:

```
from a ... from b ...
select new c
{
    TestC = b.Foo,
    TestDictionary = new Dictionary(b.Parameters.ToDictionary(
                  x => x.ParameterKey, x => (object)x.ParameterValue)) 
                 {
                   {"SomeKey", b.SomeValue},
                   //{"SomeOtherKey", b.FooBar} //if you had more than one…
                 };
}).ToList()
```